# JQuery - Scroll to top of page, then reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

Working on a restart button for a visualisation I am building. It's a png with an onclick event as follows:

```
  $('.restart').on('click', function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow").then(location.reload(true));
  })});
```

I thought that, by the way I wrote this, that the page would scroll to the top and then reload. But that isn't happening, it'll scroll a small amount and then reload.

Could you please help me in getting this function working? Click > Scroll Top > Refresh

Comment: Could you try with jQuery's `complete` parameter? `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow", "swing", function() { location.reload(true); });`

Comment: It's still reloading during the animation, and it's showing the refresh at the bottom of the page :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be of help

```js
$("a[href='#top']").click(async () => {
 await $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
 await setTimeout( () => {
  location.reload(true);
 },300);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Scroll to the top of the page with jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
  <p>jquery</p>
<a href='#top'>Go Top</a>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A great solution, thanks for sending this across. Welcome to Stack!